# Why are multiline comments allowed in empty functions but not single comments?

Tags: python

I am using python 2.7

My ide will display `indent expected` if I write a function like this

```
def foo():
    #
```

but not if I write this

```
def foo():
   '''
   '''
```

Is there any reason why this happens?

Comment: Because a (multiline or not) *string* is actually code (and is used as the `__doc__` attribute at the start of a function), but *comments* aren't.

Comment: I'm curious - did some book, professor, website or other resource tell you that `'''` introduces a multi-line comment? If so, can you tell me who/what that was?

Comment: Note:  it's not specific to multi-line strings.  A def with only the empty string `''` underneath is valid in python as well.

Comment: @Robᵩ  well, Guido himself has said it... https://twitter.com/gvanrossum/status/112670605505077248

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A comment is something that's ignored by the compiler. When you put a comment on the line the compiler basically pretends it doesn't exist. But a multi-line *string* is a physical element of the code. Python recognizes its presence and makes no complaint.

If you want to write a function that doesn't do anything, at least for the moment, use `pass`.

```
def Foo():
    #Comment goes here
    pass
```

`pass` is a keyword that says 'something should go here, but I'm purposefully not putting anything here'.

Answer (score 3):

`'''` is not actually a comment.  It acts like one, but is, in fact, a string delimiter.

Try:

```
>>> s = '''
... '''
>>> print(s)


>>> repr(s)
"'\\n'"
>>> s = #
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    s = #
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> s = '''foo'''
>>> print(s)
foo
```